# Не срабатывает кнопка CloseWin

Tags: opera, javascript, php

Здравствуйте.
Есть PHP-страничка с кодом отправки письма, на ней есть кнопка [закрыть] на ней событием
onclick="CloseWin()".
Если страничка только открыта, то кнопка срабатывает.
А если, в ней (в этойже форме) нажать [отправить], то срабатывает method=post target="_self" и почему-то кнопка [закрыть] уже не срабатывает.
Ведь это же работа JavaScript'а у клиента на бродилке.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function CloseWin()
    {
        close()
    }
</script>
```

В коде странички PHP код JavaScript и после нажатия остаётся. Почему так происходит?

Comment: JS консоль показывает какие-нибудь ошибки?

Comment: в DreamWiever нет. И Что странно! Алерт срабатывает.
дополнил функцией CloseWin2. Ввел перепенную $Close она подставляет в баттон первую или вторую функцию: onclick="<?php print $Close;?>()"
Но результат на том же месте.
Почему так? Почему срабатывает Алерт хоть от первой, хоть от второй функции, а Close - нет? браузер Опера 12

Comment: @I_CaR лучше упорядочивать метки в порядке значимости чтобы "форумчане" лучше ориентировались в это множестве разнообразных вопросов

Comment: Понятно, а минус за то, что бы не задавал вопросов на которые ни кто не может дать ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ: ЭТО КОСЯК - именно браузера ОПЕРЫ!
Везде РАБОТАЕТ! (а интересно есть костыль на эту тему?)

Answer (score 0):

";" поставьте после close() - close();

Comment: не помогло. Может прописать вторую функцию на Close?